# Is there a way to use a point other than the origin as the center for "edit object" "add object"?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I am making a simple gun that is rotated on it's base by the mouse (sort of like a cannon), and am not using rays for firing, but an object parented at the end of the barrel which uses "add object" to fire bullets. As such, the object's origin is the same as the barrel's, so that it stays at the end of the barrel when the barrel rotates. It's all fine and dandy, except for that the "add object" spawns the objects at the origin, far in the back of the barrel. This causes the bullets to come out of the side of the barrel when quickly swerving, as the bullets are not coming from the barrel's tip. So, is there a way to make the "add object" bullets come out of the tip of the barrel, where the object is placed, rather than the origin?

Comment: Maybe add the add object logic to a dummy object other than the barrel itself, like say an *Empty*? That way you can place it exactly at the end of the barrel where you need it.

Comment: I am using a separate object, just that it's origin is the same as the barrel's origin so that it rotates the same way as the barrel.

Comment: In that case it shouldn't, move it to where you want the bullet to spawn instead. If you want it to move along with the barrel then you can parent it to the barrel object afterwards, that should make it move along with it, but make it so it is correctly positioned at the desired spawn point

Comment: It IS parented to the barrel, but the origin needs to be the same as the barrel's origin so that it rotates the same way. If the object's origin was at the center of the object, it would just float in space turning weirdly, and would not move with the tip of the barrel.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to use a point other than the origin as the center for “edit object” “add object”?

No, there is not. But yes there is (but not i the way you imply with your question).

## Background

How would you tell where this point is?

Your expectation is that the projectile is inside the barrel and it moves out of it. This is correct in real live and the audience (player) should think it is this way.

But this is a game. It's purpose is entertainment. Therefore you do not care things that are not even visible to the audience (projectile in a barrel is not visible).

As you noticed having a projectile inside the barrel is not something the physics engine really want to deal with.

You correctly try to achieve you place the projectile right at the end of the barrel and let it travel from there. The physical effects from the time inside the barrel are just applied (the initial velocity).

Where is the end of the barrel?

*Who cares*! Just place an emitter (empty) at that location and let it emit the projectile. 
[image]

When you parent the emitter to the barrel it will follow any turns and motions.

[image]

The whole secret is: the barrel is not the emitter.

Comment: I did NOT place the projectile in the back of the barrel! The ORIGIN of the EMITTER is in the back of the barrel,so that it rotates in the same way as the barrel, so that it stays at the tip of the barrel. IT IS PARENTED.

Comment: Why is the origin of the emitter at the back of the barrel? The projectile will be created at exactly that location. When the emitter is parented already, move it to the end of the barrel (as shown above). The projectile will be added there.